# Using "safe" versions of stdio calls in MSVC and remaining cross platform?

Tags: visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I'm porting my simple Unix C code to windows using MSVC and have come across the warning C4996, "this function may be unsafe". The explanation is clear, and I can turn off the warning in the VS preferences, but I think it's worth exploring a conversion.

An example is `sprintf`, which it suggests replacing with `sprintf_s`. That causes an error on the macOS side, and I assume Linux (missing symbol). There's only perhaps 50 of these in total, so I could just #ifdef them all, but the result is ugly and I do prefer clean code.

I'm a C noob, and I'm wondering if I'm simply missing some simple solution to this, perhaps using the preprocessor? You can't simply #define it (tried that) because then both sides complain about redefined symbols, but that's about the extent of my preprocessor knowledge.

Comment: You're looking for `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Comment: Microsoft's own guidance says : "To fix this issue, we recommend you use the function or variable *safe-version* instead. Sometimes **you can't, for portability** or backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: @BenVoigt - OK that does seem to be the answer. It is annoying that any potential future users (all four of them!) will get compiler errors though.